# React Native Props Not Saving into New Array

Tags: arrays, loops, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-props

I am passing props to a nested component. The props are coming in correctly but I am unable to pass them to a new array like so:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
    const Map = ({navigation, locationsOne, locationsTwo, locationsThree}) => { //these are coming in correctly when I console.log ie: {"coords":{"accuracy":602,"altitude":0,"heading":0,"latitude":99.4210083,"longitude":-100.0839934,"speed":0},"mocked":false,"timestamp":1572363100628}
        const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([
          {
            location : locationsOne,
            title: 'One'
          },
          {
            location : locationsTwo,
            title: 'Two'
          },
          {
            location : locationsThree,
            title: 'Three'
          }
        ]);
    return (
    <MapView style={styles.map} initialRegion={currentLocation.coords}>
      {markers.map((locationTEST) => (
        console.log('location: ' + JSON.stringify(locationTEST)) //this returns nothing in the locations arrays ie: {"location":[],"title":"One"}
         <MapView.Marker
           title="This is a title"
           description="This is a description"
           coordinate={{
             latitude: locationTEST.location.coords.latitude,
             longitude: locationTEST.location.coords.longitude,
           }}
         />
      ))}
</MapView>
);
```

the value of locationsOne looks like: `{"coords":{"accuracy":602,"altitude":0,"heading":0,"latitude":99.4210083,"longitude":-100.0839934,"speed":0},"mocked":false,"timestamp":1572363100628}`

**How come I can't take the props and pass it into a new array (markers) array?**

Comment: One thing just looking at your code. It's probably not a good idea to not use `Map` as your component name. `Map` is an OOB object in JavaScript.

Comment: @johnborges good point, I updated the naming conventions but it is still not able to see the values through out the function

Comment: @Olivia I suspect if it has something to do with the json skeleton. Not quite sure but examples I have seen use the same json skeleton

Comment: interesting. i just updated with a useEffect and put in a callback array - locationsOne, locationsTwo, locationsThree and I was able to make some progress

Answer (score 2):

When `<Map/>` rendered at the first time, `locationsOne` still contain `[]`.

When props (means `locationsOne`  changed), state didn't changed.

So you should [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to update state when props changed.

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState ...

useEffect(() => {
  const newMarkers = [
    {
      location : locationsOne,
      title: 'One'
    },
    {
      location : locationsTwo,
      title: 'Two'
    },
    {
      location : locationsThree,
      title: 'Three'
    }
  ];
  setMarkers(newMarkers);
}, [locationsOne, locationsTwo, locationsThree]);
```

Comment: thank you, this is right, I am able to see the location values now but I am concerned with recursion. When I console.log I am seeing the location being loaded 1400 times. My understanding is that useEffect should only run once on the page load and then the [ ] allows us to see when the props change. They really should only be changing once, right? If so, this is another issue with my understanding of how the pages load with navigation.

Comment: did use `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` solve your problem?

Comment: I think you should get benefit of using `React.memo()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Rather then setting the useEffect callback array [] (this was bogging down the system as this re-runs the locations every time they change which was causing the locations to be called 1400 times), I just needed to setMarkers() like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newMarkers = [
    {
      location : locationsOne,
      title: 'One'
    },
    {
      location : locationsTwo,
      title: 'Two'
    },
    {
      location : locationsThree,
      title: 'Three'
    }
  ];
  setMarkers(newMarkers);
}, []);
```